# What happens between a user clicking on`redirect URL` from one's email and `useVerificationToken()` call in a server in next-auth.?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth, trpc, t3

I am creating a custom endpoint for `resendEmailVerification` that can be called in a client side using `trpc`.

#### 1. This is my code on custom`resendEmailVerification` endpoint:

```js
{
      const verificationTokenData = await ctx.prisma.verificationToken.create({
        data: {
          identifier: email,
          token: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
          expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), // expires in 24 hours
        },
      });

      console.log(verificationTokenData) // Loggin Here.

      const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/email?callbackUrl=${encodeURIComponent(
        "http://localhost:3000/profile"
      )}&token=${verificationTokenData.token}&email=${encodeURIComponent(
        verificationTokenData.identifier
      )}`;

      const server = {
        host: env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
        port: parseInt(env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT),
        auth: {
          user: env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
          pass: env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        },
      };
      const { host } = new URL(url);
      const transport = createTransport(server);
      try {
        const result = await transport.sendMail({
          to: email,
          from: env.EMAIL_FROM,
          subject: `Sign in to ${host}`,
          text: text({ url, host }),
          html: html({ url, host }),
        });

        const failed = result.rejected.concat(result.pending).filter(Boolean);
        if (failed.length) {
          throw new TRPCError({
            code: "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
            message: `Email(s) (${failed.join(", ")}) could not be sent`,
          });
        }
        return { message: "Verification email sent." };
      } catch (error) {
        throw new TRPCError({
          code: "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
          message: "Failed to send verification email.",
        });
      }
    }
```

#### 2. When I call this part from the client-side I am sending the following data:

```js
{
  identifier: 'testemail@gmail.com',
  token: '35c327ca7698f907c3400f19f5a02b48494070bc9ed6b1bdcd241baf31b4e592',
  expires: 2023-06-23T10:24:13.633Z
}
```

#### 3 Which are correctly sent via email with a redirect URL:

```js
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/email?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fprofile&token=35c327ca7698f907c3400f19f5a02b48494070bc9ed6b1bdcd241baf31b4e592&email=testemail%40gmail.com
```

#### 4 However, once I click this redirect link, my server receives this data in `async useVerificationToken(identifier_token)` inside `@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js`:

```js
{
  identifier: 'testemail@gmail.com',
  token: '1fe03f64155ca194a9c9997f43b3655ce8ca6b9436aa3e5ebd2e4a60a5b04bba'
}
```

#### Question: What could be the cause of this change of token values??

**client's sent token**:
`35c327ca7698f907c3400f19f5a02b48494070bc9ed6b1bdcd241baf31b4e592`

**server's received token**:
`1fe03f64155ca194a9c9997f43b3655ce8ca6b9436aa3e5ebd2e4a60a5b04bba`

I am assuming there is a certain logic when the server receives the token from the client. I would like to know it so that I can complete my custom `resendEmailVerification` functionality.

Thanks.